# passing ‘const CMyclass’ as ‘this’ argument of ... discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, function-pointers, pass-by-reference, lambda

compiling the following code via

```
g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp
```

gives me the following error:

```
test.cpp: In lambda function:
test.cpp:17:128: error: passing ‘const CMyclass’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘void CMyclass::my_method(const state_type&, double)’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
  std::function<void(const state_type &,const double)> observer = [=](const state_type &x,const double t){my_class.my_method(x,t);};
                                                                                                                                ^
```

I have searched other similar questions but I can't figure out what is wrong with this code.

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

typedef std::vector<int> state_type;

class CMyclass
{
public:
    void my_method( const state_type &x , const double t )
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    CMyclass my_class;
    std::function<void(const state_type &,const double)> observer =
         [=](const state_type &x,const double t)
         {
             my_class.my_method(x,t);
         };
}
```

**edit:**

I would not put `const` after the method.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Since you're taking by value `my_class` becomes `const`-qualified. You have three options to fix it:

1. Add `const` to your method:

   ```
   void my_method(const state_type &x, const double t) const
   ```
2. Capture by reference:

   ```
   [&](const state_type &x, const double t) { .. }
   ```
3. Or make the lambda mutable:

   ```
   [=](const state_type &x,const double t) mutable { .. }
   ```

Comment: second option was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You have to mark your lambda mutable

```
observer = [=](const state_type &x,const double t) mutable {my_class.my_method(x,t);};
```

full code below

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

typedef std::vector<int> state_type;

class CMyclass
{
public:
    void my_method( const state_type &x , const double t )
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    CMyclass my_class;
    std::function<void(const state_type &,const double)> observer = 
        [=](const state_type &x,const double t) mutable {
            my_class.my_method(x,t);
        };
}
```

compiled by `g++ -Wall -std=c++11`, gcc v4.9.2

Answer (score 0):

> passing `const CMyclass` as `this` argument of `void CMyclass::my_method(const state_type&, double)` discards qualifiers

The error message says all. `void CMyclass::my_method(const state_type&, double)` expects a normal instance but not a `const` one. Change the method definition to

```
void CMyclass::my_method(const state_type&, double) const;
```

to resolve the error, or change the `[=]` lambda initialiser to whatever you need there (e.g. `[&]`, but make sure it is not const.